# Чем один SQL запрос отличается от другого?

Tags: sql

База данных: MySQL 8.0.29

Почему тут я получаю ошибку:

```
SELECT `id`, `bonusCount` 
FROM `bonus_program` AS `bonus_program` 
WHERE (
   `bonus_program`.`bonusCount` = 41019 
   AND `bonus_program`.`id` > 0
) 
GROUP BY `bonusCount` HAVING `bonusCount` = 41019
```

Ошибка:

> SQL:  SELECT `id`, `bonusCount` FROM `bonus_program` AS
> `bonus_program` WHERE (`bonus_program`.`bonusCount` = 41019 AND
> `bonus_program`.`id` > 0) GROUP BY `bonusCount` HAVING `bonusCount` =
> 41019
>
> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
> nonaggregated column 'local_dev.bonus_program.id' which is not
> functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

А так работает:

```
SELECT `id`, `bonusCount` 
FROM `bonus_program` AS `bonus_program` 
WHERE (
    `bonus_program`.`bonusCount` = 41019 
    AND `bonus_program`.`id` > 0
) 
GROUP BY `id` 
HAVING `bonusCount` = 41019
```

Ведь во втором случае `bonusCount` тоже не участвует в goup by?

То есть стоит заменить:

```
GROUP BY `bonusCount`
```

на

```
GROUP BY `id`
```

И все работает. Хотя по-прежнему:

```
SELECT `id`, `bonusCount`
```

Comment: в группировке должны быть все поля кроме агрегатов, но поскольку у вас второе поле - константа. его в группировке можно игнорировать. хотя в целом синтаксический анализ пропускать такое не должен бы конечно

Comment: @teran `bonusCount`? Простите, не могу понять, почему оно - константа. Ведь в таблице оно имеет разные значения. А как его сделать не константным, в запросе, для понимания?

Comment: первый запрос допускает несколько различных id для одного и того же bonusCount. Во втором запросе такой вольности нет.

Comment: в таблице то они разные, но в запросе фильтруются с явным значением

Comment: Ок, а так работает, почему?: ```SELECT `id`, `bonusCount` FROM `bonus_program` AS `bonus_program` WHERE (`bonus_program`.`bonusCount` > 41019 AND `bonus_program`.`id` > 0) GROUP BY `id` HAVING `bonusCount` > 41019``` Или тут тоже константа?

Comment: А `id` случайно не уникальный в таблице? если нет, то должна, просто обязана, быть ошибка.

Comment: @Akina `id` имеет индекс `PRIMARY` и `Auto Increment`

Comment: Необязательно. Достаточно простой уникальности, плюс надо учесть, что все записи с id IS NULL будут отброшены (т.е. каждая группа по id состоит из одной записи). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a6c6e6323c75e173c463e8e08b2b5154

Comment: @Akina, спасибо. Но, как я понимаю, на это полагаться не стоит. Все поля из `SELECT` должны быть в `GROUP BY`, верно?

Comment: Если не нужны агрегаты - то и GROUP BY не нужен. Достаточно DISTINCT.

Comment: *как я понимаю, на это полагаться не стоит.* Однозначно. Время идёт, приложения меняются, потребуется изменить структуру и убрать уникальность с поля - и приложение обвалится... оно надо?